# Make echarts xAxis starts not from 0

Tags: echarts

I am using scatter chart from [eCharts scatter](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bubble-gradient). No option in official documentation about any option for setting the start of axises, I need xAxis starts not from 0, but setting some buffer like in picture

[image].

So bubble should start not from 0 but having some extra buffer, so the bubble should not overlap the xAxis. I tried boundaryGap for both xAxis and yAxis, but still axises start from 0. Any possible workaround for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `xAxis: { onZero: false }`.

Comment: for echarts 5, it's xAxis: { axisLine: { onZero: false } }

Answer (score 2):

On echarts 5.4 it is

https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.min

for x `xAxis: {min: 'dataMin'}` or y `yAxis: {min: 'dataMin'}`